# Ubuntu 12.10 freezez on startup, ocassionally

Tags: 12.04, startup

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on a virtual machine(VMWare).  No sometimes, about 50% of the time, when I start the machine up, it freezes at a point, most of the time at the point shown in the attached image(see image).

When resetting the virtual machine once or twice, it boots normally again.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google says you just have to explicitly set it in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

> ServerName localhost

Restart apache afterwards.

Comment: Thank you.But I do not have such a file: httpd.conf in /etc/apache2. I only have an apache2.conf file, and it does not have a line: ServerName . Should I set it like you said in the apache2.conf file?

Comment: If I remember this right, it is sometimes httpd and sometimes apache2. I thinks it is safe to try adding it to apache2.conf.

And yes, there is no ServerName in the conf by default.

Comment: @DextrousDave, did it work?

Comment: So far so good. Did not have a freeze on startup. I will monitor this and come back to you if it happens again. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated